# CrawlSpider can't parse multipage in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

The CrawlSpider I've created is not doing it's job properly. It parses the first page and then stops without going on to the next page. Something I'm doing wrong but can't detect. Hope somebody out there gives me a hint what should I do to rectify it.

"items.py" includes:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class CraigslistScraperItem(Item):
    Name = Field()
    Link = Field()
```

CrawlSpider names "craigs.py" which contains :

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from craigslist_scraper.items import CraigslistScraperItem

class CraigsPySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craigs"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/npo/',
    )
    rules=(Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = ('sfbay\.craigslist\.org\/search\/npo/.*',
    ),restrict_xpaths = ('//a[@class="button next"]')),callback = 'parse',follow = True),)
    def parse(self, response):
        page=response.xpath('//p[@class="result-info"]')
        items=[]
        for title in page:
            item=CraigslistScraperItem()
            item["Name"]=title.xpath('.//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/text()').extract()
            item["Link"]=title.xpath('.//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/@href').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

And finally the command I'm using to get CSV output is:

```
scrapy crawl craigs -o items.csv -t csv
```

By the way, I tried to use "parse_item" in the first place but found no response that is why I used "parse" method instead. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't name your callback method `parse` when you use scrapy.CrawlSpider. 
From Scrapy [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider):

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.

Also, you don't need to append an item to list since you already using [Scrapy Items](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) and can simply yield item.
This code should work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from craigslist_scraper.items import CraigslistScraperItem


class CraigsPySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craigs"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/npo/',
    )
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('\/search\/npo\?s=.*',)), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        page = response.xpath('//p[@class="result-info"]')
        for title in page:
            item = CraigslistScraperItem()
            item["Name"] = title.xpath('.//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/text()').extract_first()
            item["Link"] = title.xpath('.//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/@href').extract_first()
            yield item
```

Finally for output in csv format run: `scrapy crawl craigs -o items.csv`

Comment: Thanks a zillion vold for your sweet and fruitful effort. It works perfectly fine. You made my day. By the way, two things I would like to get update with. How did it click the next page button as you didn't use "restrict_xpaths" option and secondly the result is filling up the csv every alternate row. I meant, a line gap between each result. Thanks once again.

Comment: You are welcome! Well, using `restrict xpaths` for me seems redundant since you already specify regex in `allow` parameters that match only url in next button (actually two buttons but it's irrelevant). For a complete info [read this](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#topics-link-extractors).
About csv output, my result looks like [this](http://icecream.me/2a5113ac37c04ab59e6637743e95d008)

Comment: Also if you want to save a full link you can amend code to 
`link = title.xpath('.//a[@class="result-title hdrlnk"]/@href').extract_first() item["Link"] = response.urljoin(link)`

Comment: I was expecting exactly what you did just now. Thanks once again.